# I am getting invalid option -- 'x' when trying to load configuration from an XML file

Tags: uwsgi

I want to deploy my django project on my server.

The step to load the uswsgi configuration which is in a XML files is giving me the following error:

```
uwsgi -x /home/chaney/launch/Django/webtest/webtest/webtest_socket.xml
uwsgi: invalid option -- 'x'
getopt_long() error
```

However, in `uwsgi` documentation it says `'This option may be set with -x from the command line.'`

So why does it comes to me with a error message?

Comment: As the problem is with the `uwsgi` build configuration, I have removed the django tag.

Answer (score 1):

you have built uWSGI without xml support, use another format or rebuild it after having installed libxml2 or expat. When you build uWSGI a report is printed with its features. xml must not be False.

Comment: How to use another format? I install uwsgi with command make, not python setup.py build. Does that would come any problem ?